# addign additional columns in ngx-datatables

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I'm using `Angular 6` and using [ngx-datatable](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable) to add datatable in my application.

In the template file, I am using following code to display datatable

```
<ngx-datatable
  [columns]="columns"
  [columnMode]="'force'"
  [headerHeight]="40"
  [footerHeight]="50"
  [rowHeight]="'auto'"
  [limit]="10"
  [rows]='rows'>

  <ngx-datatable-column name="Actions" prop="action">
    <ng-template ngx-datatable-cell-template let-rowIndex="rowIndex" let-value="value" let-row="row">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">Success</button>
    </ng-template>
  </ngx-datatable-column>

</ngx-datatable>
```

and the columns array is like

```
columns = [
{
  prop: 'subsidiary.title',
  name: 'Subsidiary',
  sortable: true
},
{
  prop: 'app_name',
  name: 'App Name',
  sortable: true
},
{
  prop: 'app_url',
  name: 'App Url',
  sortable: true
},
{
  prop: 'db_host',
  name: 'Host',
  sortable: true
},
{
  prop: 'created',
  name: 'Created',
  sortable: true
},
{
  prop: 'action',
  name: 'Actions',
  sortable: false
}
];
```

But this is showing only one column

[image]

Removing `<ngx-datatable-column>` is working fine but there is no **Action column**.

[image]

**How can I add `Action` column or additional columns in the datatable?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you specify one `ngx-datatable-column`, you will have to specify them all. That is why everything works fine in case of no explicit column.

It should work fine if you add the other columns explicitly - no need to add the template:

```
<ngx-datatable-column name="Property 2" prop="prop2"></ngx-datatable-column>
```

... etc.